# why does chefDK contains *.hpp and *.h files

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems, chef-infra

I noticied that when install chefDK, it will install a lot of *.hpp *.h files, why?

`/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c/AbstractMemory.h
...
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/dep-selector-libgecode-1.3.1/lib/dep-selector-libgecode/vendored-gecode/include/gecode/int/unary/subsumption.hpp`

And it also need Xcode in mac, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly because we compile everything from source and the package is like 100mb so 10k of text files below our notice. Also some of them are needed afterwards if you want to `chef gem install` something with a c extension. Xcode is not needed, we have already compiled everything you need for you.